# TYPE v_id IS table of table@dblink.column%type;

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have table 'test' in schema A and from schema B I want to run the test query.
so created DBlink to A.test and dblink name 'dbl_test' .

now, I am able to query as

```
select * from test@dbl_test;
```

but when I try to use `TYPE v_id IS TABLE OF test@dbl_test.id%TYPE;` in plsql procedure block with cursor, it is giving errors as must declare and dbl_test is another database and not able to access.

When I query the select statement it is working why not for TYPE?

Answer (score 3):

Put the column before the `@`:

```
TYPE v_id IS TABLE OF test.id@dbl_test%TYPE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Database links are used to link two **databases**, not schemas.

In your case it is unclear if you really need a database link. Are your two schemas in the same database? If they are, you need only give the relevant rights to schema B and he will be able to reference schema A's datatype. I Think `GRANT SELECT ON A.TEST TO B` should be sufficient to reference its datatype.

**Edit:** it is actually possible to reference a remote datatype (I didn't know!) See [@jonearles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15555894/119634).

Comment: Thanks for the Clarification.  if I would like to create the variable type for remote database table, how can I acheive this.

Comment: @Vincent You actually can create this dependency.  Although it's a bit unusual, and it's probably better to just hard-code the types.